# two classes -> returned values

Tags: c++, class, return-value

I have 2 classes: Bucket and ExtHash

How do I assign the returned value of a function from the class Bucket to a element from the class ExtHash? Why doesn't my implementation work?

```
template <typename E, size_t N = 15> 
class Bucket
{
    size_t local; 
    size_t bucket_size;
. . .
 public:
E value1;
E value2;
...
E get_value1(){
return value1
}
E get_value2(){
return value2
}
....
};

template <typename E, size_t N = 15>
class ExtHash : public Container < E >
{
    size_t hash_size;
...
public:
...
virtual E function() const override;

};

template <typename E, size_t N>
E ExtHash<E, N>::function() const {
...
E last = Bucket<E, N>::get_value1(); //How should it look ???
E prev = Bucket<E, N>::get_value2);//How should it look????
...
}
```

Comment: why my implementation doesn't work***

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a *class* and an *instance of a class?* You have a class `Bucket`, but you do not have a `Bucket`.

Comment: yes i know the difference... I don't know how to assign the result of a function to a value. (I thought it is almost  the same as the library std ...std::cout<<"...."; )

Comment: Do you understand that `get_value1()` is not a static function, and what that means?

Comment: No :(... I don't know. What is a static function?

Comment: It's a member function you can use without an instance of the class. This function isn't static. *You need a `Bucket`.* Think about it-- what do you expect this function to return?

Comment: @Beta Sir, you just triggered a Mr. Creosote flashback.